# How to draw edge between points in two different tikz-pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, edge, drawing

how can I draw an edge between point a (=O) in the first picture and d (=1) in the second picture:

```
\usepackage {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin {tikzpicture} [-latex, node distance= 1cm]

\node [circle, draw] (a)  {0};

\node [circle, draw] (b) [right=of a] {1};

\node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north west) {M};

\end {tikzpicture}

\vspace {2cm}
\begin {tikzpicture} [-latex, node distance= 1cm] 

\node [circle, draw] (c)  {0};

\node [circle, draw] (d) [right=of c] {1};

\node [circle, draw] (e)[right=of d] {2};

\node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north west) {N};

\end {tikzpicture}
```

[image]
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `remember picture` option to access coordinates from other tikz pictures:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin {tikzpicture} [remember picture,-latex, node distance= 1cm]

\node [circle, draw] (a)  {0};

\node [circle, draw] (b) [right=of a] {1};

\node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north west) {M};

\end {tikzpicture}

\vspace {2cm}
\begin {tikzpicture} [-latex, node distance= 1cm,remember picture] 

\node [circle, draw] (c)  {0};

\node [circle, draw] (d) [right=of c] {1};

\node [circle, draw] (e)[right=of d] {2};

\node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north west) {N};

\draw[overlay] (a) -- (d);

\end {tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what if there was third pic with also a node called say `a` in it. How does it know which pic it means when writing `(a)--(d)` ? Since there are two nodes now called `a` in two different pics.  Are node names global then and not localized to each pic?

Comment: @Nasser Tikz will use the most recent a. Normally they are localized, but `remember picture` can make them available to other tikz pictures.

Comment: @Nasser You can play with https://pastebin.com/RVjj9wEm

Comment: Thanks. This is good to know. But I think it will confusing to have two different nodes called the same name and the name used globally like this. A better solution for Tikz would have been to be able to name the pic itself. So one can do `pic1.a` and `pic2.a` and so on. But I do not think one can give the whole pic a name.

Comment: @Nasser You can use the `name prefix=...` option if you want